# Send one message to multiple social media networks

Tags: php

I'm developing an app where users can send a message to multiple social media networks. Before they do, they have to fill in their user credentials.

Is there any smart library which I can use in PHP to simply send one message to multiple social media platforms (twitter, facebook, linkedin etc.)? I can achieve this by adding all the functionality separately, but I assume there must be a faster way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't believe there's a library that offers integration with all major social media networks. Note that the networks require radically different authentication mechanisms - for example, with twitter as of a couple months ago, you cannot authenticate with just the user's login/password, you need to use OAuth.

So if I were you, I would find the top-of-the-line libraries for each social network (start with 2 or 3), and integrate them one-by-one.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you will have have to sign up for all the social network APIs and integrate individually. Best of luck.